# Setting Paths for Tensor flow with GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is my environment:
Windows 10 Pro
Tnesorflow 2.6.2
Visual Studio 2022
Nvidia Studio drive 512.15
CUDA 11.6
CuDNN v8.3
cuDNN64_8.dll installed, path C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin
zlibwapi installed in Cuda/11.6/bin/zlibwapi.dll

I have freshly reinstalled all the drives and am confused on setting the paths.
I using the Environment Variable tool under System properties.

The tensor fflow installation document states:
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\extras\CUPTI\lib64;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%

What is the Variable name (CUDA, Cupti, etc for each)
What would the path setting be for each of the above

I'm stuck here and would appreciate any help.

CUDA 11.6 is at C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6
CUPTI is at C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\extras\CUPTI
Cudnn64_8.dd is at C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin
Tools is at C:\tools\cuda
Is the %PATH% setting just the location as listed above?

Comment: You are just reposting the same question that was closed in slightly different form. Still you are not describing the problem but asking about what you think the solution is.

Comment: Hi Bill! This seems to be cuda driver linkage issue.  Could you install GPU drivers suitable to Windows from NVIDIA site and create a new conda environment with TF 2.9 or higher , then install cuda toolkit 11.2 and cudnn 8.1 with conda channel .  [Ref](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip ) . Note: Visual Studio 2019 is tested and supported (Not sure on Visual Studio 2022).